# php categories tree seach by name and get parent-child node?

Tags: php

This is my db struct，named `t1`:

```
    +----+-----------+------------+-------+
    | id | parent_id | name       | level |
    +----+-----------+------------+-------+
    |  1 |         0 | cars       |     1 |
    |  2 |         1 | ford       |     2 |
    |  3 |         2 | red        |     3 |
    |  4 |         2 | blue       |     3 |
    |  5 |         0 | Airs       |     1 |
    |  6 |         5 | AirBus     |     2 |
    |  7 |         5 | Boeing     |     2 |
    |  8 |         6 | blue       |     3 |
    |  9 |         5 | white      |     3 |
    | 10 |         5 | green      |     3 |
    +----+-----------+------------+-------+
```

When I want to search by name, return the id, names of parent and child, separated by /

Example:

- search keywords = cars,result:

  ```
  array:4 [ 
    0 => array:3 [
      "id" => 1
      "name" => "Cars"
      "level" => 1
    ]
    1 => array:3 [
      "id" => 2
      "name" => "Cars/ford"
      "level" => 2
    ]
    2 => array:3 [
      "id" => 3
      "name" => "Cars/ford/red"
      "level" => 3
    ]
    3 => array:3 [
      "id" => 4
      "name" => "Cars/ford/blue"
      "level" => 3
    ]
  ]
  ```
- search keywords = ford,result:

  ```
  array:3 [ 
    0 => array:3 [
      "id" => 2
      "name" => "Cars/ford"
      "level" => 2
    ]
    1 => array:3 [
      "id" => 3
      "name" => "Cars/ford/red"
      "level" => 3
    ]
    2 => array:3 [
      "id" => 4
      "name" => "Cars/ford/blue"
      "level" => 3
    ]
  ]
  ```
- search keywords = blue,result:

  ```
  array:2 [ 
    0 => array:3 [
      "id" => 4
      "name" => "Cars/ford/blue"
      "level" => 3
    ]
    1 => array:3 [
      "id" => 8
      "name" => "Airs/Airbus/blue"
      "level" => 3
    ]
  ]
  ```

In summary, if the search result is level 1, get all sub-level categories; if it is level 2, get the upper and lower level categories; if it is level 3, get the 1st and 2nd level categories.

My idea is to add a new field fullName to the form. When saving, maintain the superior category name according to the level it is in. When searching, search according to fullName. But at present, I don't have the authority to modify the database, and I want to implement it algorithmically.

Here is origin array :

````
```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'ford',
    'parent_id' => 1,
    'level' => 2,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 3,
    'name' => 'red',
    'parent_id' => 2,
    'level' => 3,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 4,
    'name' => 'blue',
    'parent_id' => 2,
    'level' => 3,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => 5,
    'name' => 'Airs',
    'parent_id' => 0,
    'level' => 1,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => 6,
    'name' => 'Airbus',
    'parent_id' => 5,
    'level' => 2,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'id' => 7,
    'name' => 'Boeing',
    'parent_id' => 5,
    'level' => 2,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'id' => 8,
    'name' => 'blue',
    'parent_id' => 6,
    'level' => 3,
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'id' => 9,
    'name' => 'white',
    'parent_id' => 5,
    'level' => 3,
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'id' => 10,
    'name' => 'green',
    'parent_id' => 5,
    'level' => 3,
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Cars',
    'parent_id' => 0,
    'level' => 1,
  ),
)
```
````

Comment: You are tagging this question as PHP, are you searching for a php solution or laravel solution? also if laravel, show what you have done so far, controllers? models?